# How to get name from twitter id with php

Tags: php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to get my all follower's list, i uses OAuth. my code is here.
by this code i get alll id list with comma like

> [51] => 378176058 [52] => 565040748 [53]

how to get all followr's name with twitter profile link :(

```
<?php
require_once('tmhOAuth.php');
require_once('tmhUtilities.php');
$profile_username = "savanpaun"; //twitter username
$oauth_access_token = "Your access token"; //Your access token
$oauth_access_token_secret = "Your access token secret"; //Your access token secret
$consumer_key = "Your key"; //Your key
$consumer_secret = "Your secret key"; //Your secret key

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    'user_token' => $oauth_access_token,
    'user_secret' => $oauth_access_token_secret,
    'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => false
));
$code = $tmhOAuth->request(
    'GET', 
    $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/friends/ids'), 
    array(
        'screen_name' => $profile_username,
        'count' => '300'
    )
);
$response = $tmhOAuth->response['response'];
$following_ids = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($following_ids);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup) API call.

In the above example, you would call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=378176058,565040748
```

That will return an *unordered* list of all the users.  You can parse it to find the names.

Comment: but how to put it ? i already get result like [51] => 378176058 [52] => 565040748 [53]

Comment: If you make that request, you'll get `[{"id":378176058,"id_str":"378176058","name":"Tina Gunn","screen_name":"iTinaGunn",...`